# Creating Zip archive from git ls-files list using ArchiverJS

Tags: node.js, zip, glob

I am trying to create a `zip` archive using [`archiverjs`](http://archiverjs.com/docs/Archiver.html#bulk) that contains only the files that `git ls-files` would show, less some exclusions.

My code to get the file names is

```
var listFiles = function() {
  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var child;

    child = exec("cd ..; git ls-files", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      if (error !== null) {
        return reject(error)
      }

      var result = stdout.split("\n");
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
  return promise;
};
```

Then my actual bundling function looks like

```
DeploymentUtil.prototype.CreateApplicationVersionBundle = function (pathToApplication,
                                                                    versionLabel,
                                                                    target) {
  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      // Create the archive
      var output = fs.createWriteStream(versionLabel + ".zip");
      output.on('close', function () {
        resolve(output);
      });

      var archive = archiver.create("zip");

      // Error handling
      archive.on('error', function (err) {
        reject(err);
      });

      // get the files from git
      listFiles().then(function(files) {
        var exclusions = [
          '!**/.keep',
          '!.codeclimate.yml',
          '!.csslintrc',
          '!.travis.yml',
          '!env_sample',
          '!spec/**'
        ];

        for(var i = 0, l = 9; i < l; i++ ) {
          console.log(files[i]);
        }

        archive.bulk([{
          expand: true,
          cwd: pathToApplication,
          src: files.concat(exclusions),
          dot: true
        }]);

        archive.pipe(output);
        archive.finalize();
      }).catch(reject);
  });
  return promise;
}
```

Running this `archive.bulk` throws an error: `must provide pattern`.

If I replace `src: files.concat(exclusions)` with `[**/**]` however it works (only I get a lot of files I don't want in my archive).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from git ls-files will contain a terminating newline character.

When you then call `split("\n")` on the`result`, you will get an array where the last element is the empty string (`""`).

ArchiverJS probably does not like an empty string as a pattern.

One solution is to trim the string before splitting it:

`var result = stdout.trim().split("\n");`

Comment: An alternative fix would be to filter out empty strings, since this is what ArchiverJS doesn't like. something like stdout.split('\n').filter(function(e) {return e!== '';});